# Access to third party content - iFrame, signed applet, anything?

Tags: cross-browser, browser

I want to build an application (a demo, no vile intentions) which would do the following:

- a user receives an URL: `http://experiment.com/?url=destination.com`
- the user opens the URL in a browser (any browser)
- the browser enters the link, the application loads `destination.com` **using user's browser settings, cookies, etc.**
- the application saves (anyhow: user side, server side) the content of `destination.com` that was presented to the user

In a perfect, exemplary case, I would like to load iFrame and later access content of the frame. Although, I know it violates [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). The application can be server-side or client-side (like a signed applet with full permissions, or JS), although it should be cross-browser and cross-platform.

I thought about a browser extension, but it is not cross-browser. Another option would be to make the  Java applet request the `destination.com` URL, but the applet would have no access to the `destination.com` cookies... Note that I do not necessarily need an access to the 3rd party cookies, I just need to load a content using the cookies.

Any good idea here?

**Edit**:

- assume you have full permission from the user (both "legal" permissions and permissions granted to the application)

Comment: JavaScript is not on the server side, but on the client side

Comment: Yes yes yes. Mistake in a rush, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer: that's not possible: Cookies lie on the client side, and each site can only access it's own cookies.

This means: the first 3 points on your list are feasible.

The last point can only be done by monitoring the network traffic on the client machine, which is first of all not that easy, and second: plainly illigal, without permission from the user.

Of course, you could try to run a programm on the client computer which reads the browsers cookie directory and spies the data, but that again would be illigal.

Might I ask what you need this for?

Regards

Comment: Research purposes, nothing evil :) I thought about using I was using a proxy that monitored the traffic, but that needed the proxy to be set up in the browser

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the content presented by destination.com to the user, you can use [DOM](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/index.htm)

to read the html presented to the user.

```
window.frames[1]
```

This code should get you a reference to the iFrame on your page, if there is only 1 iFrame.

Comment: And what about the Same Origin Policy? Won't I get `null` when accessing the content from other domain using JS?

Comment: I'd suggest you try it out. Most important part of research is experiment ;) Make sure to post back the result.